# How do you list folders in hashicorp vault in hvac on a specific path?

Tags: python, hashicorp-vault

So I'm trying to get a list of all the folders (secrets) in a specific path (secret engine).

I've tried the below two methods, but the first one using list_secrets keeps saying I'm using an invalid path:

```
    vault_token = <token>

    vault_url = <url>

    client = hvac.Client(url=vault_url, token=vault_token)
    
    secrets_list = client.secrets.kv.v1.list_secrets(
        path = 'customerkeys'
    )

    print("secrets list: ", secrets_list)
```

while the second one using .list just returns None even though there are supposed to be two secrets in that secret engine:

```
    list_folders = client.list('customerkeys/')

    print('List of folders: ', list_folders)
```

Does anyone have any insight as to what I might be doing wrong here?